# Public Site URL visualforce page is coming up in classic instead of lightning for Guest User

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, site.com, guest-user, lightningstylesheets

I have created a public URL using sites. The site page has a custom visualforce page as the Active Site Home Page.

My issue is that when I open the public URL, the Visualforce page is coming up in classic view instead of lightning.

I have added lightningStylesheets="true" as well as <apex:slds /> in my visualforce page, but it still doesn't show up in lightning. The 'Lightning Features for Guest Users' checkbox is checked for my site.

The Guest User profile has access to the Visualforce Page as well as the corresponding Apex class.

I am not sure why I am not being able to render the page in lightning.